# adding new column to table with column name as present days date

Tags: java, database

I am new to java .I want to build simple java application for attendance management system.For doing this I want to create a new column into already existing table the column name should be present days date.I used date picker for getting  present days  date.
I had written following code for this,but the column name in table is setting as "+s1+".
This is my code:

```
    String s="";  
    s=date.getText();//selected data from date picker
    s.replace(".","_");
    try{
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasu");
       st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
       //System.out.println("ALTER TABLE attendance  ADD "+s+" varchar(50);");
       rs = st.executeQuery("ALTER TABLE attendance  ADD '"+s+"' varchar(50);");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    }
```

could any one help me
well thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `catch(Exception ex){ }` to `catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`executeUpdate` return 1 if the query work properly otherwise it will return 0

```
String s="";  
s=date.getText();//selected data from date picker
s.replace(".","_");
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    ResultSet acrs;
    String op = "jdbc:odbc:vasu";
    Connection cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(op,"username", "password");
    Statement mystmt = cnn.createStatement();

    int successOrFailure = mystmt.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE attendance ADD '"+s+"' VARCHAR(50)");
    //executeUpdate return 1 if the query work properly otherwise it will return 0

}catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE TELL ME WHATS THE USE OF i

Comment: executeUpdate return 1 if the query work properly otherwise it will return 0...with that we can check whether our query works properly or not without any exception